# How to change one side's size for ios segmented control?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder, ipod

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KxdM.png

I have this segmented control that I made, however I don't know how to shrink the left button, since there is too much space on the right and left.  any suggestions?

theres a link to the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use the method [`setWidth:forSegmentAtIndex:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006807-CH3-SW16) of the UISegmentedControl to control the width of a segment.